# how to concatenate matrix into one in a loop?

Tags: matlab, string-concatenation

i want to concatenate some data from n files into one matrix after a loop. Now the following codes work, but how can i add all the `date_1, date_2,.....,date_n` into `date`?

```
date_1     =   cell2mat (data{1,1}{1,1});
date_2     =   cell2mat (data{1,2}{1,1});
date       =   [date_1;date_2];
```

Thanks.
--Jackie

Comment: How `date_1`, `date_2` look like? Are they strings, vectors, matrices? Same size or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 date = [];
 for ii = 1:n
    date = [date; cell2mat(data{1,ii}{1,1})];
 end
```

Should work if I understand your data. If it doesn't please say so in the comments.

By the way this is not efficient, especially when n is large; but without knowing more about your data it is hard to write something more efficient...